# Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed. Something wrong with MakeIndex

Tags: makeindex

When I tried to compile (`pdfLaTeX`+`MakeIndex`+`BibTeX`), I get the same error ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372824/compile-error-after-miktex-update-sorry-but-miktex-compiler-driver-did-not-s)): Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed. I think the problem is with the `MakeIndex`, since I can use the `pdfLatex`, while all the indices and references are missing.

I have tried some solutions, e.g., reinstall the `MikTex2.9`, but I still cannot solve the problem. Please could anyone help me?

---

I add the `\makeindex` command in the preamble and run the tools individually several times. It seems fine. I don't know the reason.

Comment: Don't use texify (which is normally used by the "pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX" button), call the tools individually. Then you will get much better error messages. texify is a pain.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice. The pdfLatex and Bibtex are normal. However, when I run MakeIndex, the error message is:  Couldn't find input index file 01 nor 01.idx.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...].    So how to solve this problem? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have index commands in your document? If yes show a complete minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I had such a hard time trying to fix it. My program stoped working out of nowhere after I was doing it normally for the whole day.

In the end I found out that the problem was in the update of fonts.

Just launch command prompt and write the line

```
initexmf --mkmaps --verbose
```

Then compile your program again.

Hope you will have my luck.