# Why won't Beamer build this?

Tags: beamer, math-mode, amsmath

I am very new to beamer, but not new to LaTeX, and for the life of me cannot find my error when trying to get started building in Beamer. I have read numerous intro guides, and I still just don't get it. This should be SUPER simple, but for some reason it will not build. I know it is a problem when I add the math environment, but not sure why.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,graphicx,tabularx,array,enumitem,multicol,tikz,wrapfig,float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{collcell}

\title{A Review of Functions}
\subtitle{Section 1.1}
\author{Ethan Lightfoot}
\institute{Gateway STEM}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Do Now}
I am just trying to type some functions $f(x)$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. If you have some trouble you should be more specific. Are you getting an error? If so, which error exactly?

Comment: The MWE compiles fine (i.e. without errors) for me as posted and seems to produce reasonable output. Can you explain what exactly does not work for you? Do you get errors? Can you share the `.log` file with us?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nGw_UPbGfd0U3qyrgTiqD2M52H_Q4cH_

Comment: Here is the text file that is produced in my folder where I store the TeX file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sZhiVnY0sSsG5pyXIgdxOo8p-adAZtqI

Comment: Found the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467153/latex-warning-there-were-undefined-references-why